# Why can't I find the flash settings menu on my Canon 5d Mark II anymore?

Tags: canon, flash, camera-settings, canon-5d-mark-ii

I have 5d mark ii and 580EX ii, the flash menu was available on the cam and used it for few days. Lately I can't find the menu anymore, I've tried several things and no positive results.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the silly question, I have to be in manual mode for the other menus to show up, something like P, TV, AV, M or B.

Comment: Are you the person who asked the question? Go here to have the accounts merged http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thats correct if you set the camera to automatic, you actualy lose a few other settings like the exposure, ASA and depth of field. If you are on manual - you are then able to change almost any setting inside the camera. apperture priority and shutter priority only allow some of the settings to be changed. In many circumstances if you want best exposure, its best to leave it all on Manual and change the variables to suit the situation that you are shooting in.